# Add a symbol at the beginning of a line and add the same symbol at the ending of the line using perl

Tags: perl, filehandle

I was practising perl assignments online and found this in Sandbox.

How to Write a perl script which adds -> to the front and <- to the end of each line. It then reports the number lines, the length of the longest line, and the total number of bytes in the original input. For instance, the input file

```
//Input File 
    Hi there.
    This is Fred.
    Who are you?
```

Should produce the output:

```
//Output File
    ->Hi there.<-
    ->This is Fred.<-
    ->Who are you?<-
    3 lines, longest 13 characters, 37 bytes total.
```

I am able to add -> only at the start of the line with this code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(FH,"input.pl") or die "cannot open file: $!\n"; #Input File
open(NEWFH,"> output.pl") or die "cannot write\n"; #Output File
print "opened file\n";
while(<FH>){
  print NEWFH "-> $_ ";
}
close FH;
close NEWFH;
```

Can you please help me add the "->" at the end of the line

Comment: Sounds like homework. Since you want to learn, I only give hints, not the solution: [length](http://p3rl.org/length) gives you the size of a string. Add up the numbers to count the total.

Comment: How can I add that symbol at the end of the line?

Comment: @daxim - the question's first line explains the origin of the question. Self-learning should welcomed :)

Comment: As a side note: this isn't relevant to your question but your source for Perl code examples must be very old and probably bad. A beter Modern Perl style when opening a file uses lexical (e.g. scoped variable and not global) filehandles and 3-argument form of open: `open(my $newfh, ">", "output.pl") or die ...;` . I would highly recommend that you use more modern book/tutorial - the old style of "open" has minor problems, but is symptimatic of you not having access to better modern resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add it after the line the same way, by including it at the end of the printed string:

```
chomp; # Strip off newline character
print NEWFH "-> $_ <-\n"; # Add newline ay the end
```

As far as longest string and total count: you can use 2 variables to store the current max length and current total, and calculate them with the help of the [`length`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/length.html) function. Keep a third variable for line count.

Comment: That will not add <- at the end of every file

Comment: @Newbie - sorry, didn't notice you weren't doing a chomp. Updated.

Comment: Also, in the interest of readability, it's better to NOT use `$_` default variable as a rule - use a named one. `while my $line (<$fh>){` `chomp $line; print $newfh "-> $line <-\n";`

Comment: Your syntax is not correct. Try: `while( my $line = <$fh> ){`.

Comment: @shawnhcorey - that'll teach me not to program in comments. Quite right.

Answer (score 2):

As an exercise, you might take these one-liners and work out how they work:

```
perl -pe  's/^/->/; s/$/<-/;' input.txt
perl -ple '$_ = "->$_<-";'    input.txt
```

For a more verbose version, you add the `-MO=Deparse` switch.

Recommended reading:

- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html
- http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html (or `perl -h`, for the command line options)

Comment: RegEx seems a wee bit of an overkill for the newbie task :)  But good answer anyway

Comment: Its been so long I can hardly judge anymore what feature of Perl is more suitable for newbies. At least regexes are easy to try out. :)